# SQL queries on find Average for 2 column

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: This is the sample data]

I have a table with 3 columns being appName, Hours and Rating, I want to find the Average hours and average rating for All the apps and display it. How do i actually find the average in this situation. thank you!

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`, `AVG()`.

Comment: I have tried, it only displays the data, but it didn't calculate the avg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If appname is unique then just use group by on appname as follows:

```
select lower(appname), avg(hour) as Avg_Hour, avg(rating) as Avg_Rating
from youTablename
group by lower(appname);
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to include that app name isn't unique.

Comment: Please try the answer and if it doesn't work add the sample data into your question

Comment: I have attached the sample data. Thank you for helping me

Comment: so what do you want? Avg of whole `hour-per-week` and `rating` column? or avg of both for each `secret_identifier`?

Comment: Basically i Want to display all the app's average hours and rating, which means i have three column with each apps avg hours and avg rating.

Comment: i have tried using AVG and GROUP BY but it didn't display the avg, instead it shows all the hours and rating

Comment: because you had redundant data in your table. If you use group by app then it'll take `Facebook` and `facebook` as different app and you'll get wrong avg. Hence i am converting all appname to lowercase and then performed a group by.

Comment: Oh okay, Thank you very much for your help in this, really appreciate

Comment: `lower(app)` will covert string into lowercase and so it'll make  `Facebook` and `facebook` same and hence you can group them and find it's avg rating and hours.

Comment: Glad it worked. Feel free to ask if you've any doubts.